# Flutter Hybrid Composition and Keyboard Overlap

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In my Flutter application I have a form which is encapsulated within a native view using hybrid composition. Tapping an input at the bottom of the form opens the keyboard. This causes the keyboard to overlap the focused form field.

**How can I get the keyboard in Flutter to not overlap the form field in the native view component?**

Below is my current layout:

```dart
    SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Card(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 0),
            color: Colors.white,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
              child: Container(
                height: 520,
                child: AddressDetailsNativeView(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Take your column widget inside singlechildscroll view widget this will prevent the overlap of the keyboard.

```
SinglechildscrollView(

child:Column(
 children:[
      TextField(),
      TextField()

          ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This seems like a good solution for pure Flutter components but I'm not sure it'll work with hybrid composition: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Hybrid-Composition. I'm doing something similar (updated my question above). The `AddressDetailsNativeView` contains the form. When tapping on a native control within the form like an Android EditText, the form doesn't scroll.